# angular $http.get / restangular call fails

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, cors, restangular

I have an ionic app (uses angular js).  I am trying to make a call to my localserver (node express) using the restangular api (have also tried using $http.get).

I set the base url as

```
RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('https://localhost:3000');
```

I have an interceptor defined to add a custom header:

```
interceptors.serialNumber = function (element, operation, what, url, headers, query) {
  return {
    headers: angular.extend({
      'x-serialnumber': deviceStore.serialNumber
    }, headers)
  };
};
```

I have tried the following restangular call:

```
Restangular.one('Admin').get()
     .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
       });
     }, function (error) {
       console.log(error);
     });
```

and the following using a $http call:

```
$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://localhost:3000/Admin',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'x-serialnumber': '000000000'   
        }
      }).then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

I always get the error condition where data=null | status=-1 | statusText=""

I do not see ANY request on the server side.  It goes to the fail case immediately.

If I remove the custom header, I see the requests on the server side and get a good response (i.e. 200).

On the server side I am using the cors module:
    var app = express();
    app.use(cors());

Comment: All evidence point to deviceStore.serialNumber throwing a null pointer exception (deviceStore is undefined)

Comment: Thank you for the response Andonaeus.  I verified it is not null.  Also the $http case I hard code the header value (x-serialnumber) and get the same error as the rectangular case

Comment: If you're using CORS, have you added the custom header to the list of allowed headers?

Comment: @Amy is right, you need to add an exception (don't know why I thought we were talking about CSRF, not enough coffee)

Comment: Thank you for the responses.  I tried the following on my node express server (using expressjs\cors module):   var corsOptions = {
  allowedHeaders: 'x-serialnumber'
};
 
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

Comment: This did not work, I still get the same error and no indication on my server that a request came to it.  Also I eliminated using cors on my server side and get the same error.

Comment: Use Fiddler and see what the server is responding with.  We need more diagnostic information.

Comment: The GET request is never getting out.  I am using chrome://inspect to debug.  I set a breakpoint before the restangular call.  When I run I see in chrome developer tools \ network - the Status of the request is canceled. The Method says OPTIONS, the type says Pending.  After the angular call createHttpBackend($browser, createXhr, $browserDefer, callbacks, rawDocument), I hit the requestError() function in angular.

Comment: A few other notes, in the previous comment when the restangular call is made, on my server side I verified that no request was sent.  I can also use PostMan (GET request) to the same URL with the following two headers:  X-SerialNumber | Content-Type and the GET request works as expected.

Comment: Just a little bit more information.  When I set RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http:xxxx); it works.  It is only when I have it set to RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('https:xxxx'); that it fails.  A request is never sent out of my ionic app.  Stepping through the angular code I get a requestError() on a rejected promise.  The only difference is when I use the https it fails and http works.

Answer (score 0):

Well what I needed to do was the following:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://example.com/DUMMY'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://example.com',
    headers: {
      'x-serialnumber': deviceStore.serialNumber
    }
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    console.log('SUCCESS');
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log('FAILURE');
  });
}, function errorCallback(response) {
  console.log('FAILURE');
});
```

In essence, I needed to send a "**preliminary**" GET request with **NO** custom header.  The GET request could be to anything on my node express server.  After this "**preliminary**" GET request, I could perform the GET request with the custom header in it.

Specifically on the server side I see the following:

```
GET /DUMMY 200 10ms - 2b
OPTIONS / 204 1ms
GET / 200 13ms - 1.03kb
```

Without performing this "**preliminary**" get request, the OPTIONS request in my Ionic App would **abort -  status code = -1** - usually means the request was aborted and would never leave Ionic App side.

I still do not understand why I need this "**preliminary**" GET request, but this works for me.